# Algorithm for simulating Card game shuffle cheating

Tags: algorithm, math, random, shuffle

I would like to create a shuffling algorithm for an online TCG that would simulate the passive shuffle cheating tcg players do.

Specifically; a way to randomly shuffle a deck, however keeping similar and identical cards de-clustered in the final result.

For example, in MTG, a deck shuffled in this way would have a random distribution of cards in any way where there would be no cluster of more than 6-7 or less than 3-4 lands in any set of 10 cards.

A way I would like to do this is by being able to give different ways cards match a "weight", and have these weights repel each other in the shuffle, but I'm not sure how to incorporate this into an otherwise random shuffle.

Any suggestions on methods to achieve this or other more "natural" shuffles?

Comment: Here is an idea: (1) Initialise the shuffled deck to an empty list, and keep all the remaining lands in one data structure, and all the remaining non-lands in another data structure. (2) Maintain a value `p` that tells you the probability that the next picked card is a land, and that the next picked card is a non-land. (2) Loop: (2.1) Pick a card at random in one of the two remaining-cards sets and append it to the shuffled-deck list; (2.2) Update probability `p` depending on the number of remaining lands and non-lands and on the number of lands in the last 10-cards window.

Comment: @stef I was considering this but it has a few issues:
1. This does not keep consistency between the ends and the middle of the deck. The shuffle should be uniform through the whole deck.
2. The actual use case would be with a deck without any "lands", but multiple cards will have a different degree of "similarity" which I want to apply this shuffle method to, so the method would need to account for multiple similarity measures which multiple cards can be part of more than one similarity grouping(possibly all with different weights).

Comment: Then you can design a function that calculates, for each remaining card, how similar it is to the 10 previous cards; then normalize these similarity values into probabilities that sum to 1, and choose one of the remaining cards at random following these probabilities.

Comment: @Stef, ah yes, good idea! I would still need to think about whether this could cause issues with having different positions in the deck with different distribution likelyhoods. I could "cut" the deck randomly afterwards to fix this, but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: It will certainly give different positions different overall probabilities, yes. Imagine if the deck has exactly three cards A, B and C, where B is similar to both A and C, but A and C are not similar. Then B is unlikely to end in the middle - either it'll be picked as the first card, or A or C will be chosen as the first card, and both will "repel" B and decrease its probability to be chosen as the middle card.

Comment: @Stef, yeah exactly, but thanks for the suggestion either way, maybe a variant of this could be an idea?

Comment: I think no matter the algorithm, you can't avoid this fact that "different places have different distributions". It's inherent to what you're asking. The first 9 and the last 9 cards are in fewer groups of 10 cards than the middle cards, and you're asking something specific for every group of 10 cards. No matter the algorithm, cards that are similar to many cards are more likely to end up at the extremities of the deck where they'll be further away from similar cards; and cards that are dissimilar to many cards are more likely to end in the middle where they'll act as separators.

Comment: @Stef, not exactly, if the algorithm instead of creating the deck from the start instead "organises" an already shuffled the deck, it could treat the deck as circular and so have the ends be the same as the centre.